# How can I compare read(1.proto) = read(2.proto) in Go(assuming there's just one message definition)?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Context: I'm trying to resolve [this issue](https://github.com/arkiaconsulting/terraform-provider-confluent-schema-registry/issues/9#issuecomment-873461267).

In other words, there's a `NormalizeJsonString()` for JSON strings (see [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23928) for more context:

```
// Takes a value containing JSON string and passes it through
// the JSON parser to normalize it, returns either a parsing
// error or normalized JSON string.
func NormalizeJsonString(jsonString interface{}) (string, error) {
```

that allows to have the following code:

```
return structure.NormalizeJsonString(old) == structure.NormalizeJsonString(new)
```

but it doesn't work for strings that are proto files (all proto files are guaranteed to have just one message definition). For example, I could see:

```
            syntax = "proto3";
          - package bar.proto;
            
          + package bar.proto;
            option java_outer_classname = "FooProto";
            
            message Foo {
              ...
          -   int64 xyz = 3;
          +   int64  xyz = 3;
```

Is there `NormalizeProtoString` available in some Go SDKs? I found [MessageDifferencer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer) but it's in C++ only. Another option I considered was to replace all new lines / group of whitespaces with a single whitespace but it's a little bit hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in a semantic fashion, the proto definitions should really be parsed. Naively stripping and/or replacing whitespace may get you somewhere, but likely will have gotchas.

As far as I'm aware the latest official Go protobuf package don't have anything to handle parsing protobuf definitions - the `protoc` compiler handles that side of affairs, and this is written in C++

There *would* be options to execute the `protoc` compiler to get hold of the descriptor set output (e.g. `protoc --descriptor_set_out=...`), however I'm guessing this would also be slightly haphazard considering it requires one to have `protoc` available - and version differences could potentially cause problems too.

Assuming that is no go, one further option is to use a 3rd party parser written in Go - [github.com/yoheimuta/go-protoparser](https://github.com/yoheimuta/go-protoparser) seems to handle things quite well. One slight issue when making comparisons is that the parser records meta information about source line + column positions for each type; however it is relatively easy to make a comparison and ignore these, by using [github.com/google/go-cmp](https://github.com/google/go-cmp)

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp"
    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp/cmpopts"
    "github.com/yoheimuta/go-protoparser/v4"
    "github.com/yoheimuta/go-protoparser/v4/parser"
    "github.com/yoheimuta/go-protoparser/v4/parser/meta"
)

func main() {
    if err := run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func run() error {
    proto1, err := parseFile("example1.proto")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    proto2, err := parseFile("example2.proto")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    equal := cmp.Equal(proto1, proto2, cmpopts.IgnoreTypes(meta.Meta{}))

    fmt.Printf("equal: %t", equal)

    return nil
}

func parseFile(path string) (*parser.Proto, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    return protoparser.Parse(f)
}
```

outputs:

```
equal: true
```

for the example you provided.

Comment: is there an equivalent for `cmp.Equal(proto1, proto2, cmpopts.IgnoreTypes(meta.Meta{}))` using `reflect.DeepEqual`?

Comment: Not an exact equivalent - the only option if you want to use `reflect.DeepEqual` would be to zero the `Meta` fields before calling the function

Comment: do you mind sharing an example? I think that may work really well.

Comment: A few options here - https://gist.github.com/nick-jones/f3669c4bebaa593dd96aad2e82e5e30f - but none are anywhere near as succinct as just using the `cmp` package